# UIView as subview won't clip to superview

Tags: swift, uiview

I have a superview with rounded corners.
It has a custom subview (`UIView`) that will cover the rounded corners of it's superview. (so the superview will look like it doesn't have rounded corners)

I tried on subview :

```
  self.clipsToBounds=true
```

but it will still cover the corners of its superview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the clips to bounds on your superview.